# Update 2nd Textbox Based On Popup Calendar Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using the JavaScript-based popup calendar from dynamic drive named
"[Xin's Popup Calendar](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex6/popcalendar2.htm)" and it works perfectly. But, I want to be able to
adjust the date of a 2nd textbox based on the selection.

For example, I want to be able to automatically adjust it to +1 month of
whatever date was selected in the popup.  How can I do that?

Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" name="firstinput" size=20>
<small><a href="JavaScript:showCal('Calendar1')">Select Date</a></small>

<p>
<input type="text" name="secondinput" size=20>
<small><a href="JavaScript:showCal('Calendar2')">Select Date</a></small>
</p>
```

If the `firstinput` date is 3/21/10, I want the `secondinput` to change to 4/21/10 at the same time.

Comment: Do you want this change only when the pop-up is used?  Not when a user hand-enters a date?   That is, should the second input always be 1 month apart from the first, no matter what the user does?

Comment: Yes, if by off chance they hand enter it, I'd like it to autoadjust to +1 month as well, but it's important to note that I want them to still have the ability to manually override the adjustment.  So, just because it went to 4/21/10, they can still change it to 4/17/2010 for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this: (1)  a function to add a month to a data and (2) the change event handler to the textbox. This solution is very specific to the [Xin Pop Up Calendar](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex6/popcalendar2.htm).

```
function addMonth(d,month){
 t = new Date (d);
 t.setMonth(d.getMonth()+ month) ;
 if (t.getDate() < d.getDate())
  {
   t.setDate(0);
  }
 return t;
} 

$("input[name='firstinput']").change(function(){

var dt = $(this).val();
var yr = dt.substring(0,4);
var mo = dt.substring(5,7);
var dy = dt.substring(8,10);

var firstDate=new Date();
firstDate.setFullYear(yr,mo-1,dy);

var secondDate = addMonth(firstDate,1);
$("input[name='firstinput']").val(secondDate.getFullYear() + "/" + secondDate.getDate() + "/" + secondDate.getMonth()+1);

});
```